# 24 gear SRAM shifters- PROBLEM

Tags: repair, gears, shifter, sram

So recently i bought a carrera vengeance for £45 which is a bargain and the only problem was the gears(24 gear SRAM shifters) for the left side. When i got it i tried to shift but it just clicks and nothing happens, there is also a strong resistance. Someone please help.

Comment: Is it a twist shifter?

Comment: Is it new or used?  I suspect it was super cheap because of this gearing problem.    Can you describe the problem further, using photos as well?  Does the front derailer work right?   I guess 24 speed is a triple on the front and 8 cogs on the rear cassette.   If you hang the bike up and manipulate the rear derailer directly does it work?  What if you tension the right inner cable by pulling it while the bike is hanging?  More troubleshooting needed.

Comment: The left side shifter is the front derailleur, which is independent of the rear.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a strong resistance. My guess is that you have a limit screw preventing the fron derailleur shifting to bigger chainring.

Check limit screw

Check if front derailleur can move freely (unscrew both limit screw and pull the cable to see if front derailleur move). Sometimes front derailleur corrodes to the point that it cannot be moved.